# Java web application to use for testing of servers

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, stress-testing, sample

I'm looking for a simple open source, or reference application that I could use for testing some Java servers. The primary server would be Tomcat, and the database backend is MySQL. Are there some reasonable sample applications out there that are fairly easy to get up and running with?

The ideal application would be fairly stateless in nature and be accessible without authentication so that it could be easily used for stress testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [spring](http://www.springsource.org/) examples, [PetClinic](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/SpringPetClinicsampleapplication.htm) and [JPetStore](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/SpringJPetStoresampleapplication.htm). In these links you can find some more applications.